# Loop Vertically One column at a time

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, sass

I wanted to loop through an array of objects and show 4 of them vertically in one column before displaying the items in the second column.

Right now I can print the items like this

[image]

I need it like this

[image]

I can always break down the array into 2 sub-arrays and display it individually in each column. Was wondering if there was a better way to implement it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-acelg2

Comment: It may be better to let the rendering be handled by CSS and you pass it the data.  IIRC flexbox allows you to specify the direction of the items in which case you can make it flow vertically and wrap back to the top row.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the heigth of your elements, you can always split your data in an array of two elements

```
serviceColumn=[this.serviceList.filter((_,i)=>i<4),
               this.serviceList.filter((_,i)=>i>=4)]


<div style="display:flex">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1]">
    <div *ngFor="let service of serviceColumn[i]">
      <span>{{ service.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ service.count }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use slice pipe

```
<div style="display:flex">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1]">
    <div *ngFor="let service of serviceList | slice: i * 4:(i + 1) * 4">
      <span>{{ service.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ service.count }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you has an observable, not an array you can use some like

```
<div style="display:flex" *ngIf="serviceList$ | async as list">
  <div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1]">
    <div *ngFor="let service of list | slice: i * 4:(i + 1) * 4">
      <span>{{ service.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ service.count }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1dcx8j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

## The CSS way:

Instead of using `flexbox` on your container, why not use `column-count` ?

> The column-count CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns.

[MDN : column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

### Demo:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>item 1 - 10</li>
  <li>item 2 - 20</li>
  <li>item 3 - 30</li>
  <li>item 4 - 40</li>
  <li>item 5 - 50</li>
  <li>item 6 - 60</li>
  <li>item 7 - 70</li>
  <li>item 8 - 80</li>
</ul>
```