# How to insert HTML close tag programmatically

Tags: angular

Is there is a method to close an HTML tag with a `*ngIf` condition, with template only?

For example, I have a table with 4 columns. When the `largeView` is False I would slit rows in 2 columns:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>first name:</td>
      <td>{{firstName}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!largeView">
        </tr><tr>
      </ng-container>
      <td>last name</td>
      <td>{{lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No there isn't, you'll have to create separate blocks. If you need to share some code, you should probably use ng-templates !

Comment: The idea is create an array of arrays (acording your requeriments the first array can to have an unique element or two) and makes twoo concatenated loop. Some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391071/loop-vertically-one-column-at-a-time/71391698#71391698)